# Creating Facebook dummy users

Tags: facebook

Is there any regulation about creating dummy Facebook accounts to test apps? What do you do when you need many account to test application you are developing?

Comment: well try it and find out :D (seriously i dont know the answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/

There are some issues that people find annoying, like the block that test accounts can't use normal Facebook features means you can't test the viewing of friends lists and such.

Comment: Note that test users can see other *test* users friend lists, and apps for which test users have given permission can also see the test user's friend lists. All that is generally prohibited is test users from interacting with real users. However, agree that there are still some frustrations!

Answer (score 1):

You'll see online people mentioning creating test accounts... most people have different accounts for their application environments (dev, test, prod)...

If you need many accounts, get your friends to test :-)

HTH.